# Access violation reading location 0x50F9BF08

Tags: c++

I have written a code that solves 3n + 1 problem
but when i run it and input (1 200000) i get
**Access violation reading location 0x50F9BF08**

I don't know what this exception is and I'll be very thankful if someone helps
here's my code:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;

#define MAX 1000000
long int cycleLengthResult[MAX] = { 0 };

long int cycleLength(long int num)
{
    if (num > MAX)
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0)
            return 1 + cycleLength(num / 2);
        else
            return 1 + cycleLength(3 * num + 1);
    }
    else if (cycleLengthResult[num] == 0)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (num == 1)
            count = 1;
        else if (num % 2 == 0)
            count = 1 + cycleLength(num / 2);
        else
            count = 1 + cycleLength(3 * num + 1);
        cycleLengthResult[num] = count;
    }
    return cycleLengthResult[num];
}

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    long int max;

    while (cin >> i >> j)
    {
        max = 0;
        cout << i << " " << j << " ";

        if (i > j)
        {
            int temp;
            temp = j;
            j = i;
            i = temp;
        }

        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++)
        {
            cycleLength(k);
            if (cycleLengthResult[k] > max)
                max = cycleLengthResult[k];
        }
        cout << max << endl;
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are going off the end of your array.  I would add checks to make sure you don't do that and if you do have it print so you know where an when this happens.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: i debug it and it breaks at line 17

Comment: @Mohammad In that case, you did not debug it. You just launched your program with debugger attached, and looked at the results. You did not step through your code with it, nor you looked at variable values at each step, to see where it derails from your expectations. Please, do not state that you debug it, when you didn't.

Comment: i have visual studio 2015 professional the problem is there is no trace table here

Comment: That sounded like an insane thing for the VS developers to leave out, Mohammad, so I just checked. I have a pair of tabbed panes at the bottom of the debug layout. One lists Autos, locals, and watches. The other lists  Call Stack, Breakpoints, and a few others. All the good food a debugger needs.

Comment: If you are crashing on this line: "else if (cycleLengthResult[num] == 0)" then make sure that "num" is always less than "MAX".

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good chance you are overrunning the cycleLengthResult array. Certainly the expression in the `if (num > MAX)` clause is suspicious - if num is odd it will certainly exceed the array boundaries.

One way to figure this out easily is to not use a raw array, but a `std::array`, and access it not using `operator[]`, but using member function `at()`. `at()` has the additional bonus of doing bounds checking for you, so you can see where your function fails.

Comment: how can it exceed the array boundaries?

Comment: i used array class but there is no difference

Answer (score 0):

You are overflowing the limit of the `long int`. If you would have debugged the code you'd see that the issue happens when you recursively call `return 1 + cycleLength(3 * num + 1);` with `num` being 827370449, thus `3 * num +  1` is 2482111348 (which is more than LONG_MAX or 2147483647) and subsequently `cycleLength` is called with `num` being -1812855948. You can fix this by using an unsigned value `long int cycleLength(unsigned long int num)`. I did not devote time to look at the actual algorithm but you may be better of with a 64bit value for `num` if the value grows really big.